# android service syntax error in button onClick

Tags: android, button, service, onclick

Service is not starting. It gives me a syntax error under the button onclick to start the service at startService(intService); It looks like the service is declared correctly but it is asking me, under the onclick for the button, to declare the service as a variable

```
    public class Ship extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
private static final String TAG = "ShipService";
public static final Integer[] TIME_IN_MINUTES = { 30, 45, 60, 180, 360 };
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
public Handler handler = new Handler();
public Button button2;
public Button stop1;
public Spinner spinner2;

// Initialize the activity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.ship);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    stop1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    stop1.setOnClickListener(this);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TIME_IN_MINUTES);

  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
    Intent intService =  new Intent(Ship.this, Shipservice.class);
    intService.putExtra("TIME_IN_MINUTES", 1000);
    startService(intService);

}

// Handle button callback
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intService =  new Intent(Ship.this, Shipservice.class);
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn2:
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting service");
        startService(intService);
        break;
    case R.id.stop:
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");
        stopService(new Intent(this, Shipservice.class));
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you post the full code. also declare `Intent intService` as a class member and initialize it in `onCreate` and call  `startService(intService);` on button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare and initialize your `Intent` variable in `onCreate`. It is a local variable to the `onCraete` method. You should declare your variable as a class member.

Comment: I have a service class, its called shipservice.class and it is what I set the intService equal to.

Comment: Read again: `intService` is not defined in `onClick`, only in `onCreate`.

Comment: so adding Intent intService =  new Intent(Ship.this, Shipservice.class); under the onclick, above the switch statement, should fix the issue? I just updated the code to reflect that